# Autocorrelation of Truncated Gaussian Random Process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Consider $X=X_r+jX_i$  to be a circularly symmetric Gaussian random variable, and $$X\sim\mathcal{N}_c(0,\sigma^2)$$ where $\mathcal{N_c}$ denotes the Gaussian distribution for complex random variable. Here $X_r$ and $X_i$ are the real and the imaginary parts of $X$. Due to circularly symmetry assumption, zero mean random variables $X_r$ and $X_i$ are independent and identically distributed (i.i.d) with each $$X_r\sim\mathcal{N_r}(0,\sigma^2/2)$$ $$X_i\sim\mathcal{N_r}(0,\sigma^2/2)$$ where $\mathcal{N_r}$ denotes the Gaussian distribution for real random variable. Now from the same random process we have two variables $X_1=X(t)$ and $X_2=X(t+\tau)$. Thus the correlation coefficient is given as

$$\rho(\tau) = \frac{E[X(t)X^*(t+\tau)]}{E[X(t)X^*(t)]}$$

For present case,  $\rho(\pm T)= \rho_1(constant)$.

It is clear that $E[X(t)X^*(t)]=\sigma^2$ and $E[X(t)X^*(t+T)]=\rho_1\sigma^2$

Now, I need to calculate $$\mathbb{E}[XX^*(t+T)||X|<a,|X(t+T)|<a]$$

$$\mathbb{E}[|XX^*(t+T)|^2||X|<a,|X(t+T)|<a]$$ $$\mathbb{E}[|XX^*(t+T)|^4||X|<a,|X^*(t+T)|<a]$$

where $a$ is a constant.